# BlazeDS serialization with complex types

Tags: apache-flex, serialization, blazeds

I recently came into a situation when sending a nested object from Java to Flex via a HashMap the Objects were null. More precisely:

```
final Map<Integer, List<String>> tempMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();
```

would send the keys as integers but the values were all null.

But when sending the same with String keys:

```
final Map<String, List<String>> tempMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
```

the objects came thru.

Are there any restrictions in BlazeDS serialization when using complex types as keys?

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn on property errors in your services.config.xml:

   ```
   <channels>
    <channel-definition id="YourChannel" class="mx.messaging.channels.AMFChannel">
    <endpoint url="http://{server.name}:{server.port}/{context.root}/messagebroker/amf" class="flex.messaging.endpoints.AMFEndpoint" />

    <properties>
     <polling-enabled>false</polling-enabled>
     <serialization>
      <ignore-property-errors>false</ignore-property-errors>
      <log-property-errors>true</log-property-errors>
     </serialization>
    </properties>

    </channel-definition>
   </channels>
   ```
2. Try to remove final keyword and try it without it. I had problems serializing final fields with blazeds